# Group Theory (basic)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $N$ be a subgroup of $G$. Assume that $|G| =
2 |N|$. Prove that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Please don't give me the answer. I just want some help in thinking about this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But why are there only 2 cosets? So we know that the order of N must divide the order of G because N is a subgroup (by Lagrange's Theorem). Since N is half the size of G, does that mean that there are only two left or two right cosets?

Comment: Think about how many elements a coset has.

Comment: I think I've got it. Since the cosets form a partition of G, N can only have two cosets. The two left cosets must look like the two right cosets since, by definition, they partition the Group. Am I right?

Comment: The fact that the left and right cosets coincide does not immediately follow from the fact that they partition the group. For example the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ has two different partitions $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$ and $\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$. However in your question the cosets can be described more specifically. Think about the left coset $eN$ and the right coset $Ne$.

Comment: I've hit a block. Can I assume that g^(-1)Ng = gNg^(-1) ?

Comment: Or what if I say that G = Nr U Np where r,p are in G and show somehow that G = lN U sN where s,l are in G and that s,l = p,r, respectively ?

Comment: You cannot just assume that $g^{-1}Ng = gNg^{-1}$ holds for an arbitrary element $g \in G$. The situation you describe in your last comment is what you eventually want to prove. To help you along the way: can you describe the coset $eN$?

Comment: The coset eN is just the subgroup, N correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So what do you know about the other left coset? And can you say something similar for the right cosets?

Comment: Then the other left coset must be all values elements, gN in G that are not in N?

Comment: There's no need to think about it as $gN$ anymore. We know that one of the two left cosets is the set $N$ and the two left cosets partition the group $G$. So the other left coset is $G \backslash N$. Now what can you say about the right cosets (think about $Ne$)?

Comment: Ah, so the right coset Ne is the subgroup N again, forcing the other coset to be the same, G\N correct? So eN = Ne implies (N)G/H = H/G(N), so N is a normal subgroup

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ There are only two left cosets of $N$ in $G$. What do these cosets look like? And what do the two right cosets of $N$ in $G$ look like?

Answer (score 0):

Hints: How many left cosets are there? right cosets? what is one such coset? what is the other? are the left cosets the same as the right cosets? Is the subgroup normal?